# How to switch to another branch while recursively initing submodules

Tags: git, git-submodules, git-checkout

I have a git repository with several submodules ([see an example](https://github.com/kkarbowiak/submodules-mainrepo)). Its structure looks like this:

```
I--A--B <- main
       \
        C <- branch-c
```

- Commit A adds a `submodule-a`
- Commit B adds a `submodule-b`
- Commit C adds a `submodule-c` on branch `branch-c`

When I clone the above repo using
`git clone --recurse-submodules <URL>` only the `submodule-a` and `submodule-b` submodules get initialised and cloned.

When I then want to check out branch `branch-c` using `git checkout branch-c`, the directory for `submodule-c` gets created, but the submodule itself is not initialised. There is no indication in the command output that some additional steps are needed. Neither `git status` nor `git diff` give any hint.

When instead I want to check out `branch-c` using `git checkout --recurse-submodules branch-c` I get an error:

```
fatal: not a git repository: ../../.git/modules/subrepos/subrepo-c
fatal: could not reset submodule index
```

How do I check out (or switch to) branch `branch-c` while automatically initialising all submodules?

Comment: The "TL;DR summary" is that `--recurse-submodules` doesn't quite work. A pair of separate switch-or-checkout, followed by `git submodule update --init`, operations does work. (Even then there may be an occasional sharp edge. Submodules are awful, even when they're the right answer.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your example repository is lacking a `branch-c`, so it's not a complete MCVE, but it's a good start :)

> When I clone the above repo using `git clone --recurse-submodules <URL>` only the `submodule-a` and `submodule-b` submodules get initialised and cloned.

Yes, this is the current behaviour of `git clone --recurse-submodules`. The submodules are cloned and initialized using an invocation of [`git submodule update --init --recursive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-update--init--remote-N--no-fetch--no-recommend-shallow-f--force--checkout--rebase--merge--referenceltrepositorygt--depthltdepthgt--recursive--jobsltngt--no-single-branch--filterltfilterspecgt--ltpathgt82308203) during the [checkout phase of `git clone`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/277cf0bc36094f6dc4297d8c9cef79df045b735d/builtin/clone.c#L719-L749), and as such, only submodules recorded in the default branch (or the branch specified using `git clone -b <branch>`) are cloned and initialized.

> When I then want to check out branch `branch-c` using `git checkout branch-c`, the directory for `submodule-c` gets created, but the submodule itself is not initialised. There is no indication in the command output that some additional steps are needed. Neither `git status` nor `git diff` give any hint.

Yes, this is unfortunately still the default behaviour of Git. Submodules working trees are not checked out by default by `git checkout <branch>`. [`git submodule status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-status--cached--recursive--ltpathgt82308203) (or just `git submodule`) will show uninitialized submodules with a `-` prefixed.

> When instead I want to check out `branch-c` using `git checkout --recurse-submodules branch-c` I get an error:
>
> ```
> fatal: not a git repository: ../../.git/modules/subrepos/subrepo-c
> fatal: could not reset submodule index
> ```

This is a good reflex but unfortunately it does not work in that specific case and leads to this bad UX. `git checkout --recurse-submodules <branch>` assumes that every submodule recorded in `branch-c` are already initialized. Since that's not the case here, it errors out because it can't find the `.git` directory of the submodule. The message could be clearer. What you have to do (the first time you switch to `branch-c` after cloning your repository) is to check out `branch-c` non-recursively, and then initialize the submodule:

```sh
git checkout branch-c
git submodule update --init --recursive
```

Then, you will be able to correctly switch between your branches with `--recurse-submodules`:

```sh
git checkout --recurse-submodules main
git checkout --recurse-submodules branch-c
# etc
```

Note that you can set [`submodule.recurse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-submodulerecurse) in your config to avoid having to use `--recurse-submodules` all the time.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. My example repo does have the `branch-c`, see [it on github](https://github.com/kkarbowiak/submodules-mainrepo/tree/branch-c). I realise I can use `git submodule status` after switching branches to check whether submodules are up to date, but was hoping there is a smoother workflow with submodules (e.g. "use normal command but add `--recurse-submodules` to each"). The current git behaviour is very surprising if you do not suspect a submodule is added. In my case, I cloned a repo, switched branch and got very confusing build errors.

Comment: Sorry, I somehow missed you `branch-c` when I checked :) I agree the behaviour is suboptimal. With `submodule.recurse` set, most things pretty much work, expect for new submodules as you note.

Comment: Is there a way to do a successful `git submodule update --init --recursive` after a failed `git checkout --recursive-submodules` without having to `rm` the repository and clone it back again ?

Comment: Yeah, you should be able to run `git reset --hard && git clean -dff`, then manually remove the submodule repository at `.git/modules/SUBMODULE_NAME`, and then run `git submodule update --init --recursive`. See [my answer on the Git mailing list](https://lore.kernel.org/git/20200501005432.h62dnpkx7feb7rto@glandium.org/T/#mb92502803836f6820e891b7a3a1e7eb4b1ad86f0).

Comment: @philb Thank you very much ! Did you ever get a response to your email ? Has things have evolved ever since ?

Comment: You're welcome:) No, as you can see on the archive nobody responded. I do have some patches that fix part of the problem (namely the "could not reset submodule index" error, point 3 in my email), but I have not yet had the time to polish them and send them to the list. If you are interested they are here: https://github.com/git/git/compare/master...phil-blain:git:unpack-trees-missing-submodules