# git --recurse-submodules for non main/master branches

Tags: git, git-submodules

- I have a [git repo](https://github.com/OrenGitHub/importer/tree/main) with two branches: `main` and `feature`.
- only `feature` branch has a [git submodule](https://github.com/OrenGitHub/importer/tree/feature)

```
$ git clone --recurse-submodules  git@github.com:OrenGitHub/importer.git
$ cd importer/
$ git checkout feature
$ ls -l subby/ # <--- the submodule exists
total 0 # <--- but it's empty
```

I need to additionally do this to bring submodule content:

```
$ git submodule update --init
```

why is that?

Comment: The `--recurse-submodules` flag you pass to `git clone` applies only for that first command. If the commit checked out at this point has no submodules at all, you get no submodules cloned yet. If you `git checkout --recurse-submodules feature`, that will make Git update submodules. You can also set recursion to be on by default, except that this does not affect the initial `git clone` in the first place.

Comment: @torek this does not work for me - I get `fatal: not a git repository: ../.git/modules/subby` followed by `fatal: could not reset submodule index`

Comment: That's odd, and not supposed to happen as far as I know, but I think there are edge cases with submodules that aren't yet `update --init`-ed. I dislike the recursive modes in general because of such edge cases.

Comment: I think my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72272371/how-to-switch-to-another-branch-while-recursively-initing-submodules/72275916#72275916 should explain exactly what happens, and why `git checkout --recurse-submodules feature` returns an error.